# JQuery Postback triggered by nested DropDownListFor returning only the first row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects, which are shown using Editor Template. When a task's dropdownlistfor changes, the JSON postback always returns the values of the first task, regardless of which row's dropdownlist is updated.

I see many of the same problem, but not when the trigger is in a nested element inside a editor template.  I'm lost as to what i'm missing out here.  Help?

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.task

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_id, new { @id = "taskID" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_name, new { @id = "TaskName" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_desc, new { @id = "TaskDesc" })

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.completion_date, new { @id = "CompletionDate" })


<table style="width:80%">
<tr style="width:60%">
    <th colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_name)</th>
    <th align="left">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.task_state_id,
    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TaskStates"], "task_state_id", "state"),
                               new { @class = "ddlState"})
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.notes, new { @Id = "Notes" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_desc)</td>
    <td>@Html.Label("Completed by ")@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.user_completed)@Html.Label(", ")@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.completion_date)</td>
</tr>
</table>





   <div class="tasks">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks, new { @class = "Tasks"})   
        </div>
   </div>
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </p>

  @section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
$(this.document).ready(function () {
    $('.ddlState').change(function ()
    {
        var task = {
            "task_id": $("#taskID").val(),
            "task_state_id": $('#ddlState').val(),
            "task_name": $('#TaskName').val(),
            "task_desc": $('#TaskDesc').val(),
            "notes": $('#Notes').val(),
        }
        var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateTaskState")';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(task),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
                $("#message").html("Success");
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // Show the error
                $('#message').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })

    })
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read my comments on your last question. Your editor template is creating duplicate `id` attributes. Each row has a hidden element with `id="taskID"` which is invalid html. When you use `$("#taskID").val()` it gets the values of all the elements with `id="taskID"` but only returns the value of the first one.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i muat have missed that part.  Apologies.  Will correct and remove this post if that fixes it

Comment: I'll post an answer for the previous question a little later today showing how to do it all correctly

Answer (score 0):

your code is : new { @class = "ddlState"}) so you shoud use "task_state_id": $('.ddlState').val(), with "." not "task_state_id": $('#ddlState').val(), with "#" because it's class not id